# Почему выводиться - "this' argument to member function..."?

Tags: c++, boost

Я пытаюсь сохранить значение в JSON файл, но почему-то компилятор выводит следующую ошибку:

```
'this' argument to member function 'add_child' has type 'const pt::ptree' (aka 'const basic_ptree<basic_string<char>, basic_string<char> >'), but function is not marked const
```

В интернете ничего не нашёл по этому поводу.
Вот ссылка на github репозиторий: https://github.com/swimmwatch/SmartDictionary/
ошибка в файле main.cpp на 108 строчке
[image: место в коде, где ошибка]

Comment: Научитесь читать ошибки и предупреждения... Они довольно много о чем говорят.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил данную проблему. dict у меня передаётся в lambda функцию по значению. Если передавать по ссылке, то проблема исчезнет.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/464773)

Comment: @Victor VosMottor thanks Monica автор этого ответа является автором вопроса.)